# Is it safe lock/scope guard implementation?

Tags: c++, multithreading

For now I have this implementation of thread-safe field getting from a class:

```
int A::GetValue() const
{
    _mutex.Lock();
    int temp = _value;
    _mutex.Unlock();
    return temp;
}
```

I want to replace it with lock/scope guard implementation like this (LockGuard class has only constructor/destructor and Mutex * _mutex field):

```
LockGuard::LockGuard(Mutex & mutex) : _mutex(&mutex)
{
    _mutex->Lock();
}

LockGuard::~LockGuard()
{
    _mutex->Unlock();
}
```

And refactored code:

```
int A::GetValue() const
{
    LockGuard lockGuard(_mutex);
    return _value;
}
```

I suddendly realized that I don't sure if this a safe implementation. Is it guaranteed that firstly the copy of _value will be passed out of function and only with this copy already existed the _mutex will be unlocked?
Please don't provide C++11 alternative implementation examples - I have embedded system and unfortunatelly can't use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this program my help you visualize what happens:

```
#include <iostream>

// Replaces the int so that we know when things happen
struct Int {
   Int() {
       std::cout << "Int::Int()" << std::endl;
   }
   ~Int() {
       std::cout << "Int::~Int()" << std::endl;
   }
   Int(const Int &x) {
       std::cout << "Int::Int(const Int&)" << std::endl;
   }
};

struct LockGuard {
   LockGuard() {
     std::cout << "Locking" << std::endl;
   }
   ~LockGuard() {
     std::cout << "Unlocking" << std::endl;
   }    
};

struct A {    
  Int getValue() const {
     LockGuard lockGuard;
     return _value;
  }    
  Int _value;    
};


int main() {
   A a;
   std::cout << "about to call" << std::endl;
   Int x=a.getValue();
   std::cout << "done calling" << std::endl;
}
```

That results in

```
Int::Int()
about to call
Locking
Int::Int(const Int&)
Unlocking
done calling
Int::~Int()
Int::~Int()
```

One final note is that you might need to make `_mutex` `mutable` in your attribute declaration as locking and unlocking are typically non-const operation that would not be allowed in a const method otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand that firstly x is copy constructed from _value and only after that mutex is destroyed. And I already use mutable flag on every mutex because I prefer to use const keyword any place it could be useful to avoid potential errors. :)

Answer (score 5):

This line is a problem:

```
LockGuard(_mutex);
```

It should be:

```
LockGuard foo(_mutex);
```

Otherwise it will go out of scope and unlock your mutex before the rest of the method executes.  (you can verify the problematic behavior by temporarily inserting printf's or similar in the LockGuard constructor and destructor as well as in your calling method).

Other than that your locking pattern is good.

Comment: +1 for you. I use named LockGuard in my real code and made mistake in post code. My question so is not concerned with this problem but with function returning only.

Answer (score 4):

Your implementation of `LockGuard` is ok, but usage is wrong. With the statement

```
LockGuard(_mutex);
```

You are creating a temporary `LockGuard` which will be destroyed just after the statement is finished.

Your usage should be

```
LockGuard guard(_mutex);
return _value;
```

`LockGuard guard(_mutex);` will create a `LockGuard` object, which will lock the mutex in constructor. When the method returns, the destructor will be called, unlocking the mutex. And you no longer have to use a temporary to return.

Comment: Would you _please_ stop applying code formatting to random words? Thanks.